# Ajax call error with JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making an ajax call below and getting an error I do not understand.  The variable response in the success function looks like

```
{"status": "complete", "username": "test", "error": "0", "message": ""}
```

however when I call my three alert functions inside the success function, the first one prints out the value above, but the next two print out undefined.  I know the error key exists, however the javascript does not recognize it.  As a result my window crashes.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/index.php/api/userLogin',
    data: userInfo,
    datatype: 'json',
    async: 'false',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response)
    {
      alert(response); //prints correct response
      alert(response.error); //prints undefined
      alert(response["error"]); //prints undefined
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) 
    {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    //alert("Please Try Again, we had an internal error!");
    alert(err.message);
    }
  });
```

Can somone explain what is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Looks ot me like you want to be checking the server side code - you are getting what looks a success, but clearly not getting the other data you were hoping for

Comment: I am not sure, but if there is no error, will there be any error? So, while you succeed, response will show you the json string, but as there is no error, how can it shows you error? and I am not sure , why you are trying to get error in success?

Comment: try alert(type of response); and make sure you are getting object not string

Comment: JSON.parse(response).error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a combination of two factors:

1. The server is sending the JSON with the wrong content type
2. You've used the wrong capitalization for overriding it

Consequently, jQuery is interpreting the JSON as (probably) plain text (which is why alerting the value gives you the raw JSON and not `[Object object]`).

You should fix this by making sure the server sends the JSON with:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Since it looks like you are using PHP, you can do that with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

You should also either remove `datatype: 'json'` or change it to `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: @Tushar — The response is clearly already encoded as JSON. The OP is therefore already doing that. The problem is that jQuery doesn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

that because response is not parse as JSON object to do that you can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/index.php/api/userLogin',
    data: userInfo,
    datatype: 'json',
    async: 'false',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response)
    {
      var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response); // <---- Here parse it as JSON
      alert(data.error); 
      // Todo with data

    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) 
    {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    //alert("Please Try Again, we had an internal error!");
    alert(err.message);
    }
  });
```